# DELETE methods for HABTM associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tracks
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :release
 has_many :releases_tracks, :through => :release, :source => :tracks      
 has_and_belongs_to_many :tracks
 before_save do
   self.track_ids = self.releases_track_ids
 end        
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :releases
end

class ReleaseTracks < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :release
  belongs_to :track
end

class ProductsTracks < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :track
end
```

At the moment I can create a release and add tracks to it. When I then create a product it inherits the tracks from the release.

What I want to do is be able to delete individual tracks at the product level, but not the track entry itself, so delete the association in `ProductsTracks`.

How would I go about writing the appropriate destroy method, which controller should it reside in and how should the `link_to` be structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just destroying the tracks at the product level? I believe the default behavior is to destroy the relationship, and not the record at the other end of the relationship.

Comment: I'm actually having trouble doing that!! How should I structure my link_to?

Comment: Hmm, just off the top of my head (untested), it's something like `link_to product_track_path(@product, @track_to_delete), :method => :delete` assuming you have a nested route of tracks under products.